# C++ equivalent to the Sun Java Language Specification and JVM Specification?

Tags: c++

Does C++ have an "official" language specification document, similar to the Sun/Oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#6.6.1

Comment: That's not really hard to find, everything you need is on the [Wikipedia article on C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization).

Comment: The Oracle Java Spec contains much more detail than the C++ wikipedia article? Its 600 pages long and is THE spec....

Comment: What? Did you bother to follow the link? It explains C++ standardization and where to find the actual specification, obviously I didn't mean that the Wikipedia article _is_ the specification...

Comment: Yes i did. The way you worded "everything you need" sounded like you were suggesting the article was the spec!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++ specification can be bought from ISO for the equivalent around $300 US. The BSI imprinted version is a bit more pricey -- around $750US if memory serves.

Fortunately, the ANSI has priced [their version](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS/ISO/IEC%2014882-2012) a bit more reasonably -- $30US.

While the truly official version isn't free, if you want something really close that is free, the standard committee's web site has a [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) from shortly before standardization, and [another](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) from just after, with a few typos fixed and such.

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest to official are the [ISO/IEC 14882 standards](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?ics1=35&ics2=60&ics3=&csnumber=50372) (warning: paywall, you will not be able to download the standard without a subscription).

> ISO/IEC 14882:2011 specifies requirements for implementations of the C++ programming language. The first such requirement is that they implement the language, and so ISO/IEC 14882:2011 also defines C++. Other requirements and relaxations of the first requirement appear at various places within ISO/IEC 14882:2011.

However, as stated in a comment below, the drafts of those standards are available for free, such as [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/).

Comment: I found this for free: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/